# Объединить две таблицы с разными форматами Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Итак, есть исходный DF:

```
YEAR    COM SEC
2010    1   B
2011    1   B
2012    1   B
2013    1   B
2014    1   B
2015    1   B
2012    2   C
2013    2   C
2014    2   C
2015    2   C
```

Есть второй DF:

```
SEC 2008    2009    2010    2011    2012    2013    2014    2015
A           45      53      53      3       5       3       5       3
B           5       3       4       3       3       5       33      4
C           4       3       4       5       6       7       3       3
```

Необходимо сопоставить два DF по году и графе SEC
На выходе должно получиться нечто такое:

```
YEAR    COM SEC X1
2010    1   B   4
2011    1   B   3
2012    1   B   3
2013    1   B   5
2014    1   B   33
2015    1   B   4
2012    2   C   6
2013    2   C   7
2014    2   C   3
2015    2   C   3
```

Comment: `YEAR` во втором фрейме - это индекс или обычный столбец?

Comment: это каждый столбец называется "2010" "2011" и тд. Это просто для понятия написал, вниз идут сразу SEC, а влево YEAR, условно верхняя левая ячейка пустая

Comment: OK, значения `A, B, C` - это индекс или столбец (как называется этот столбец)?

Comment: A,B,C, это все значения из вариантов SEC, просто тут они в названии строки стоят

Comment: что выводит `print(df2.columns); print(df2.index)`?

Comment: Выводит: Index([u'SEC', 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015], dtype='object')
По второй: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)

Comment: |YEAR можно убрать, пусть там написано только SEC, я выше написал. Выводит `None`

Comment: Вы все верно поправили, в итоге кто-то изменил, сейчас все верно

Comment: Прошу прощения, уезжал в командировку. Ответ верный, благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d2 = (d2.set_index('SEC')
        .unstack()
        .reset_index(name='X1')
        .assign(YEAR=lambda d: d.pop('level_0').astype('int')))

res = d1.merge(d2)
```

Результат:

```
In [132]: res
Out[132]:
   YEAR  COM SEC  X1
0  2010    1   B   4
1  2011    1   B   3
2  2012    1   B   3
3  2013    1   B   5
4  2014    1   B  33
5  2015    1   B   4
6  2012    2   C   6
7  2013    2   C   7
8  2014    2   C   3
9  2015    2   C   3
```

---

Если столбцы, представляющие годы во втором фрейме являются числами (`[2009,2010, ...]`), а не строками (`['2009','2019',...]`), то решение можно упростить:

```
In [138]: (d1.merge(d2.set_index('SEC')
                      .unstack()
                      .reset_index(name='X1')
                      .rename(columns={'level_0':'YEAR'}))
Out[138]:
   YEAR  COM SEC  X1
0  2010    1   B   4
1  2011    1   B   3
2  2012    1   B   3
3  2013    1   B   5
4  2014    1   B  33
5  2015    1   B   4
6  2012    2   C   6
7  2013    2   C   7
8  2014    2   C   3
9  2015    2   C   3
```